# Applying manifests in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-kubernetes-service

Basically, I want the pipeline to `apply` some manifests before deploying images from ACR. No images need to be made. It would just be things like applying the `issuer.yaml`, `ingress.yaml`, and maybe a few other things that need to be run before the `client` and `api` images are pulled from ACR.

Was looking at the documentation here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops#overview

But just not really seeing what I need.

Suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, come across the answer right after asking the question.

Needed to look at the `Kubectl task` and not the `Kubernetes manifest task`. Particularly the [Commands section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops#commands):

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: kubectl apply using arguments
  inputs:
    connectionType: Azure Resource Manager
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
    azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup)
    kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
    command: apply
    arguments: -f mhc-aks.yaml
```